# How to Get Marker ID by coordinates on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, markers

I have markers on a map and a list of coordinates in a < ul > dynamically loaded.

I need to get the **marker id** by clicking on the coordinates < li >.

Would somebody have the solution?

Thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution by myself. On click on list element, i've run a loop on markers array and compared if **marker.id** had equal proprieties to the coordinates list element (**data-latitude** and **data-longitude**).

```
$(document).on('click','li', function(){
    for( i=0; i<markers.length; i++ ) {
        if (markers[i].lat === $(this).data('latitude') || markers[i].lat === $(this).data('longitude') ) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

I hope that can help someone ;)